# Voltage source absorbing/deliver power?

Tags: power, voltage

In my opinion the voltage source ABSORBS power, since the current direction and source direction are opposite.
Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can not resist: probably yes, but only you can be certain of your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You are right about the direction of current but not for the simple reason that the sources are opposite.

The sources could be opposite but current could still flow out of the 1V source (which incidentally you've shown as a current source). It all depends on the value of the the left-hand resistor not the direction of sources.

If the left hand resistor were for instance 0.5 ohms, ask yourself what current would flow in or out-of the 1V source.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that, in you're reasoning, you're not confusing the *reference direction* of the current with the *sign* of the current.

Since it appears that you have the current *I* entering the positive labelled terminal of the (oddly drawn) voltage source, a *positive* power means the voltage source is absorbing energy while a *negative* power means the voltage source is supplying energy.

So, in order to see which is the case, you must actually determine the sign of *I*.

A quick calculation reveals that, in fact, \$I = 1.5A \$ however, as Andy aka points out, if the \$2 \Omega\$ resistor is replaced with a resistor \$R < 0.5 \Omega \$, the current \$I\$ would be negative and thus, the voltage source would be supplying energy to the circuit.